# Do I have access to Android/iPhone notifications via React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'd like to control what notifications get shown and when...
Is this implementable with React Native or do I need to do it natively?

I've been looking around and couldn't find the answer, so I thought I might as well ask it.

Answer (score 2):

There is a native PushNotificationIOS implementation on iOS, but not for Android.

So, the option is to use an external library that implements both of them simultaneously:

[React Native Push Notifications](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification)

You can push them locally (from the app) or push remotely to the phone using a server like GCM (Google Cloud Messaging ) or Amazon SNS.

If you want, there is a video tutorial implementing it using this library:
https://medium.com/differential/how-to-setup-push-notifications-in-react-native-ios-android-30ea0131355e#.f050jnu7y

I haven't watched it, but it seems pretty good.

Cheers.